# using Remove and RemoveAt in Sqlcommand

Tags: c#, sql

I want using method Remove and RemoveAT to delete the value in combo box from database
I always see with using method add but now i want remove and RemoveAT

```
cmd.Parameters.RemoveAt(comboBox1.SelectedIndex);
```

I write this code but there is error in the code

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     using(cnn = new SqlConnection(v))
     {
         using(cmd = new SqlCommand())
         {
             cmd.CommandText = "SELECT name_,age FROM Table_Group";
             cmd.Connection = cnn;
             cnn.Open();

             dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

             while (dr.Read())
             {
                 comboBox1.Items.Add(dr["age"]);
             }

             dr.Close();
             cmd.Dispose();
             cnn.Close();
         }
    }
}
```

Delete routine

```
 private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     using (cnn = new SqlConnection(v))
     {
         using (cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Table_Group WHERE age = @age", cnn))
         {
             cmd.Parameters.RemoveAt(comboBox1.SelectedIndex);
             cmd.Connection.Open();
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
             cnn.Close();
             cmd.Dispose();
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: There is an error...? Are you allowed to share that with us?

Comment: Also, you're trying to remove a value from the command parameters without ever adding any. There are no parameters to remove.

Comment: Try searching about Entity Framework if you don't know about DB connector libraries.

Comment: You, probably, want something like `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", comboBox3.SelectedValue);` in order to remove value (age) which is in `combobox3` from the database

Comment: What do the docs for `RemoveAt` say? The first step in looking into programming problems is to read what the docs _say_ a method does - rather than hoping it does what you want.

Comment: `cnn.Close();
               cmd.Dispose();` Those two lines are unnecessary and can be removed.

Comment: *cnn.Close();     cmd.Dispose(); Those two lines are unnecessary and can be removed*  why like i lean is to important to close the connection

Comment: The `using` already closes them both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want

> to delete the value in combo box from database

you should *add* parameter (what to delete) instead of *removing* it. Something like this

```
using (var cnn = new SqlConnection(v)) { //TODO: don't you forget "var"?
  cnn.Open(); 
   
  // let's have sql being readable
  string sql = 
    @"DELETE 
        FROM Table_Group 
       WHERE age = @age";

  // using will Dispose for you; there's no need in Close() and Dispose()
  using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn)) {
    //TODO: cmd.Parameters.Add is a better syntax
    // I've put AddWithValue since I don't know corresponding RDBMS type
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", comboBox3.SelectedValue);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  } 
}
```

You can use `RemoveAt` if you want to remove from *combobox*, not *database*:

```
// Remove Selected Value   
combobox3.RemoveAt(combobox3.SelectedIndex);
```

Comment: yes I know I can use AddwithValue to delete but I want know to if i can use remove or removeat for delete data in database . and if isnt delete data from database than for what use ?

Comment: @Yunha: Well, `Remove` and `RemoveAt` don't have sence here. You ask sql server to delete a value which you provide via parameter; so you have to *add* the parameter (what to delete)

Comment: `but I want know to if i can use remove or removeat for delete data in database` @Yunha Why do you want to do it that way? It clearly doesn't work (you know that - **since you already tried it**).

Comment: Dmitry Bychenko @ah right I understand Thank you for help. I wounder why you **var** when it is work without it and u use it for what

Comment: mjwills @I'm still student so to learn I love trying to do some code .Yes, I know that it does not work because I tried it , but I thought that I had missed something

Comment: @Yunha: I don't like global declarations when `cnn` is used *here*, but declared *somewhere else*; that's why I use `var`: to declare variables locally when possible